# If $x+3$ is positive, then which one of the following must be positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

See: [Nova GRE Math Bible. Page-$235$.](https://greworldknowlegde.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/nova-gre-math-bible.pdf)

> **Problem#$09$**
>   If $x+3$ is positive, then which one of the following must be positive?
>   (A) $x-3$
>   (B) $(x-3)(x-4)$
>   (C) $(x-3)(x+3)$
>   (D) $(x-3)(x+4)$
>   (E) $(x+3)(x+6)$

My attempted solution was as follows.

**(A)** $x-3 \Rightarrow x+3-6$. Since $x+3$ is positive, we have $-6$ left in our hand which is negative.
So, overall, (A) is **negative**.

**(B)** $(x-3)(x-4)$
$\Rightarrow (x+3-6)(x+3-7)$.
According to the previous logic, since we have $-6$ in the first term and $-7$ in the second term, the multiplication of them is positive.
So, overall, (B) is **positive**.

**(C)** $(x-3)(x+3)$
$\Rightarrow (x+3-6)(x+3)$.
According to the same previous logic, since we have $-6$ left in the first term,
 (C) is overall **negative**.

**(D)** $(x-3)(x+4)$
$\Rightarrow (-6)(1)$.
So, (D) is **negative**.

**(E)** $(x+3)(x+6)\Rightarrow (3)$.
So, (E) is **positive**.

So, **my answer** is: (B), (E).
But, the **given answer** is (E)-only.

What is wrong with my explanation?

Comment: I don't understand your arguments.  To show that a given case might be negative I just need to show a particular example.  For $B$, for example, try $x=3.5$

Comment: @lulu $x=4$ will work too for disproving (b).

Comment: @lulu, `I don't understand your arguments.` --- that is strange.

Comment: Really, I don't understand your arguments.  The fact that $-6$ is negative has little to do with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a valid deduction for A):

Let $x = -1$. Then $x+3$ is positive, but $x-3$ is negative. So $x-3$ needn't be positive if $x + 3$ is positive.

Here is a valid deduction for B):

Let $x = 3$. Then $x+3$ is positive, but $x-3 = 0$. So $(x−4)(x-3) = 0$ So B needn't be positive if $x + 3$ is positive.

I'm sure you can do the rest.

Comment: I would be careful using the word "mustn't", meaning "must not". It suggests that something must not be the case. Instead I'd say "need not" (or "needn't"). It's not that $x - 3$ *must not* be positive when $x + 3$ is positive, but it is the case that it "need not" be positive when $x + 3$ is positive.

Comment: I agree with you. Changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is the only answer because $B$ is not always true.

For example if  $x=3.5$ then $ x>-3 $ but $(x-3)(x-4)=-0.25 <0$